# trying to get currently open workbook path from excel. MyExcelAppObject.Application.ActiveWorkbook sometimes returns null

Tags: c#, .net, excel, com-interop

I am trying to get currently open workbook name (path) from excel application. The method looks like this:

```
        var ExcelObj = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
        return ExcelObj.Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName;
```

very often (almost 50% of attempts) it throws nullreferenceexception because ExcelObj.Application.ActiveWorkbook is null but sometimes it returns right value. I couldn't figure out what is the problem. Why does it work sometimes but sometimes doesn't.

Comment: You should be really careful with this. For example, it's possible to have multiple instances of Excel open and you have no control over which one you will get access to.

Comment: @Hyper could you try `Workbooks(1)` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`?

Comment: I need workbook which is currently active. It may not be the first one